# How to write to a database (postgresql) a json file in which the image is encoded using apache nifi?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, image, apache-nifi

I have the following json file in which an image is encoded in the photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxZO1.png) field:

I use standard processors to work with a JSON file and try to write this file to PostgreSQL using an ExecuteSQL processor (photo in bytea format). When writing directly, it gives an error that the char format was expected. How to write the encoded image to the database correctly using apache nifi?

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what your flow looks like, what the flowfile content looks like before the ExecuteSQL and the schema of your DB table.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.